# How to Pick Out Numbers From a String in a List (Beginner)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that should open a text file, read the entire file, and return 2 lists of integers. The lists are separated based on the letter (a or b) in front of the number, the lists should only contain numbers as well. Here's an example:

File:

```
A 47
B 175
A 126
A 36
B 2781
```

Desired output:

```
List A: ['47', '126', '36']
List B: ['175', '2781']
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
a = []
b = []
file = open('numberfile')

def number_check():
    text = file.readlines()
    for line in text:
        if 'A' in line:
            a.append(line)
        if 'B' in line:
            b.append(line)
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

My unsuccessful result:

```
Line A = ['A 47\n', 'A 126\n', 'A 36\n']
Line B = ['B 175\n', 'B 2781\n']
```

Comment: You need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the line and convert the second entry of the resulting list to an integer ([`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#int)). Additional: You don't need `readlines`, a simple `for line in file:` will work. And `file` should be a parameter of the function.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function should receive argument which is `file` open. In the function you only need to iterate the `line` of `file` then split the line and do unpacking value (`x,y`) of `line.split()`. From there, you can check if `x` value is equal to 'A' or 'B' and append `y` to the list `a` or `b` depends on the value of `x`.

```
a = []
b = []
file = open('numberfile')

def number_check(file):
    for line in file:
        x, y = line.split()
        if x == 'A': 
            a.append(y)
        elif x == 'B': 
            b.append(y)
    print(f'List A: {a}')
    print(f'List B: {b}')
    file.close()


number_check(file)

# List A: ['47', '126', '36']
# List B: ['175', '2781']
```

Don't forget to `close` the file, or you can use `with` statement to open and close the file:

```
a = []
b = []

def number_check(file):
    for line in file:
        x, y = line.split()
        if x == 'A': a.append(y)
        elif x == 'B': b.append(y)
    print(f'List A: {a}')
    print(f'List B: {b}')
    

with open('numberfile') as file:
    number_check(file)

# List A: ['47', '126', '36']
# List B: ['175', '2781']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split up the line and convert the second field to an integer.

Also, you'll want to make sure you open *and close* the file near where you read it, to avoid spaghetti code where a change in one part of the code affects the behavior of code far away in another part of the program. Where you `open`ed the file outside the function, you were setting yourself up for this sort of future complication.

```
a = []
b = []
with open('numberfile') as file:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        fields = line.rstrip('\n').split()
        if len(fields) != 2:
            raise ValueError(f'invalid input line f{lineno}: f{line}')
        value = int(fields[1])
        if fields[0] == 'A':
            a.append(value)
        elif fields[0] == 'B':
            b.append(value)
        else:
            raise KeyError(f'invalid key line {lineno}: f{line}')

print(a)
print(b)
```

Notice also that this is rather more specific than your check for `'A' in line` which would trigger if the character was found anywhere in the line. Here, we take care to verify that the input is well-formed, and prefer to abort with an exception over returning invalid results or slipping into undefined behavior. (Notice that `int(fields[1])` also performs an implicit check which will raise an exception if the second field is not a valid integer.)

The `enumerate` is just to get a line number for the error messages. Designing useful error messages which really reveal to the caller exactly what's wrong is an important skill to develop.

If you wanted to carve out a function, perhaps wrap the whole thing into a `def` which accepts a file name argument and returns the two lists `a` and `b` to the caller; but what makes sense also depends on what future directions you are planning.

Perhaps notice also that this avoids reading the entire file into memory. Instead, we read a single line at a time, handle it, and discard it. For a toy problem like this, it doesn't make a big difference, but understanding the distinction is important for situations where you need to cope with files of unknown size and provenance.

A better solution for the long haul is to use a standard input file format which Python already knows how to parse (CSV would seem natural here, though YAML or JSON could also work). Life is too short to spend it on writing ad-hoc parsers for ad-hoc file formats. (But as an exercise for learning how to parse simple files, this is a light and easy start.)